# Issue with executing commands with passwordless ssh

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

After placed public key at 171.201.231.20(windows machine with openssh installed)executed the command: `ssh -vvv Administrator@171.201.231.20 ping -help` from HP-UX machine it is not executing. Below is the ssh command trace. please help me to know the issue:

```
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug2: callback start
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug1: Sending command: ping -help
debug2: channel 0: request exec confirm 0
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 131072
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: close_write
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug2: channel 0: close_read
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r0 i3/0 o3/0 fd -1/-1 cfd -1)

debug3: channel 0: close_fds r -1 w -1 e 7 c -1
debug1: Transferred: stdin 0, stdout 0, stderr 0 bytes in 0.1 seconds
debug1: Bytes per second: 

stdin 0.0, stdout 0.0, stderr 0.0
debug1: Exit status 255
```

Comment: What is the command you are running ? Are you using an authorized_keys forced command ?

Comment: After placed public key at 171.201.231.20(windows machine with openssh installed)executed the command: "ssh -vvv Administrator@171.201.231.20 ping -help" from HP-UX machine

Answer (score 2):

Try to provide the full path for the remote command. E.g. `C:\WINDOWS\system32\ping.exe`

Comment: Even after using command with path it is acting the same. By the way scp is also not working giving the giving the below message :"debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r0 i3/0 o3/0 fd -1/-1 cfd -1)

debug3: channel 0: close_fds r -1 w -1 e 7 c -1
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: fd 1 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Transferred: stdin 0, stdout 0, stderr 0 bytes in 0.1 seconds
debug1: Bytes per second: stdin 0.0, stdout 0.0, stderr 0.0
debug1: Exit status 255
lost connection"

Comment: May be sshd can not start the shell (CMD).